# Ratio between two vectors

Tags: geometry, vectors

I'd like to know if in mathematics exist the ratio between two vectors. If yes, when is it used?

Thank you so much.

Comment: No, it's absurd. We can define it, but it's not comforting.

Comment: you can try $$\vec{a}=t\vec{b}$$ or $$\frac{|\vec{a}|}{|\vec{b}|}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, but only if they are parallel:

If $\vec{AB}$ and  $\vec{CD}$ are in the same direction then
$${\vec{AB}\over \vec{CD}} := {\overline{AB}\over \overline{CD}}$$
else
$${\vec{AB}\over \vec{CD}} := -{\overline{AB}\over \overline{CD}}$$

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking whether there is a commonly used general notion of dividing one vector by another, then no, there isn't one, for the simple reason that there isn't a common notion of multiplying one vector with anything to make a vector in a way that is invertible in the form of division.